# After upgrade to macOS Catalina, running XCUITest will keep getting 'Verifying "AAA" ...' popup

Tags: xcode, macos-catalina, xcuitest

Ever after upgraded to macOS Catalina, when run XCUITests, will keep getting "Verifying "AAA" ...' popup (AAA here is my testing app)

Anybody else get this problem? I'm on Xcode 11.3. It was fine before my macOS upgrade. Can anyone please help here? many thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SgSu.png)

Comment: Did you try deleting all simulators? Always worth doing after an update.

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for the suggestion, just tried to delete all the simulators and re-added some back, but still see the same issue.

Comment: That's certainly frustrating. Okay, I'm going to suggest you temporarily turn off SIP. Restart into recovery mode (holding down Command-R during restart), then open the Terminal in recovery mode and type start your mac in recovery mode. 
Then open the terminal and type `csrutil disable`. Restart. Now try doing the UI test.

Comment: If that doesn't work, all I can think of is erasing the hard drive and reinstalling Catalina clean.

Comment: You should try to clean-install Xcode before reinstalling the whole system!